# bad_alloc when allocating array

Tags: c++

I have this code on the constructor of a class:

```
verts=new GLfloat[nVerts];
```

verts is a member variable of the class (GLfloat *) and nVerts is 4. Is something wrong with that code? I get the same error If i try to do malloc(sizeof(GLfloat)*nVerts)
I think I'm not running out of memory, because If i change that line of code to another part of the code(for example to the method that calls the constructor just before calling it, like this: `GLfloat *test=new GLfloat[4]` it works)

Comment: Yes- what's wrong is that you should never, ever use `new[]`. Always go `std::vector<GLfloat>`.

Comment: I bet that `nVerts` is actually uninitialized.

Comment: @XaitormanX - if it were, you wouldn't get a bad_alloc. Or, that's not actually the problem.

Comment: It is, because If i change the nVerts with 4, it still doesn't work. That's why I am stranged. What other thing can be causing it?

Comment: @DeadMG but that would return a vector, wouldn't it? And I need a c array

Comment: @XaitormanX: You can use `std::vector` as C array as it is is guaranteed to to store elements in continuous memory locations.

Comment: You'll have to post more code.

Comment: It should be said that whatever it might be, changing `new[]` to `std::vector` won't help you with it.

Comment: @jpalecek But it's still a good idea.

Comment: That one line of code you posted doesn't contain any errors. This means that the error lies elsewhere, and you'll have to post the context of the snippet if you want more help.

Answer (score 4):

I'd check 3 things:

1. Are you 100% sure that `nVerts` is 4?
2. Isn't memory really exhausted?
3. Isn't your heap corrupted? valgrind can help you with that.

Comment: 2 could happen for instance if you are allocating many such objects in a loop and you forgot to write a correct destructor.